# etAPI dll. Where can I find it?

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, c#

Finding information on this is not easy. I have tried searching online etAPI with many search string various with no real results. The documentation references this dll without bothering to mention where I can get it!

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to?

Comment: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_triggered_email_campaign_workflow/

Documentation that provides a code sample of a single 200 line long function to send a simple email.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but all links are dead, any luck with this so far?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think what you might be looking for is the [Fuel SDK](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/csharp/getting-started-with-the-csharp-sdk.html) from the ExactTarget website. Salesforce are always acquiring things and changing their name.</strike>

What about [this](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/api_starter_kits/)? The .NET download has a folder called etAPI in, but I can't say for sure if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: No that's not it. Ive used the fuel wrapper before and that is not it

Comment: Any luck with the new link?